# Unable to access request parameters in JSP sent through form action using GET method

Tags: html, forms, query-string

I have a form with action as loader.jsp.

```
<form action="loader.jsp?WindowName=abc&compname=xyz" method="POST">
</form>
```

When I submit this form, Inside the loader.jsp I am able to access the request parameters using

```
String windowName = <%=request.getParameter("WindowName")%>;
```

But when I change the form method to GET I am not able to access the parameter using the above statement. It gives null.

When I inspected the request in the Fiddler, URL doesn't even contain the request parameters when the method is GET.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you set your form method to `get`, what's in the form is gonna be added as querystring and therefore the querystring inside `action` attr is being ignored. Try to add your values as hidden fields to your form to get them like:

```
<form action="loader.jsp" method="GET">
  <input type="hidden" name="WindowName" value="abc">
  <input type="hidden" name="compname" value="xyz">
</form>
```

BTW this is not a jsp issue. This is the html's `form` element behaviour.